# Using RamdaJS to convert an object to an array that includes the key of the object

Tags: ramda.js

I have the following object:

```
data = {
'key_1': {'some_prop_1': some_val, 'some_prop_2': some_val},
...
'key_n': {'some_prop_1': some_val, 'some_prop_2': some_val}
}
```

I would like to have an array like this:

```
[
{'some_prop_0': 'key_1', 'some_prop_1': some_val, 'some_prop_2': some_val},
...
{'some_prop_0': 'key_n', 'some_prop_1': some_val, 'some_prop_2': some_val}
]
```

How can I achieve this with RamdaJS?

Comment: This should be fairly straightforward with Ramda tools.  Do you have an attempt of your own  you can share?

Comment: I have solved this. I will be posting my solution in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't bother using Ramda for this.  There's a fairly simple vanilla JS technique:

```js
const convert = (keyname, data) =>
  Object .entries (data) .map (([key, obj]) => ({[keyname]: key, ... obj}))

const data = {
  key_1: {some_prop_1: 'abc', some_prop_2: 'uvw'},
  key_n: {some_prop_1: 'def', some_prop_2: 'xyz'}
}

console .log (
  convert ('some_prop_0', data)
)
```